# How do I use Keywords in Quickbooks documents?

Tags: search, quickbooks, document-management

In Quickbooks (Desktop 2022), you can upload an attachment to almost anything (a client file, an invoice, a payment) and there are several optional fields you can fill out with that attachment:

- Title (This is separate from the Document Name, which is retained from the upload and can't be changed)
- Description
- Keywords (the QB subtext for this field mentions you can use commas
  as a delimiter)
- Comments

Except when I go to search through my attachments from the Doc Center, it only seems to check my criteria against these fields:

- Doc Name (which you can't change after the upload)
- The name of whatever object it was attached to

  - (if it was attached to a client file, it could be searched by that client's name.  Sounds great, until you attach something to a client invoice and now it is checked by the invoice# instead of the client's name)
- Description

So how do I go about actually using the fields like 'Keywords'?

Comment: I use QuickBooks Desktop 2022 and manage my documents (many) via Windows. That works well for me.

Comment: Do you have any tips you could give me?  I've recently become responsible for our digital record-keeping, and I'm new to QB, so advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I keep folders of customer files and all the customer files and QuickBooks export files in those folders (sometimes subfolders for large clients to divide client files from accounting documents). It is really a file organization issue (many years of QuickBooks).

Comment: @John Are you using the location QB uses for its documents, or are you storing them elsewhere?  When do you use the QB Doc Center instead of managing files through Windows?

Comment: I have an overall folder for a client, folders for specific documents, and a folder for the QBW files.

Comment: I looked quickly at Document Center. My own file organization (part of the location for the QB data file) works better because of the variety of documents I work with.